# My cat ate an unidentified lizard! What should I do?

Tags: cats, health

My cat caught and ate a lizard. I do not know the type of lizard he ate.

- Might this affect my cat negatively?
- What signs should I look for to see if my cat is OK?
- Is it necessary to take my cat to the vet?

Comment: What kind of cat? What kind of lizard? is the cat showing any adverse symptoms you are concerned about.  This question can not be answered in the current form.

Answer (score 16):

If you are concerned about any urgent health issue with your pet, you should call a vet.

That having been said, cats are hunters and will eat small animals, including rodents, birds, bugs, and lizards.  If you don't notice anything unusual with your cat, there probably isn't anything to worry about.  But again, if you are concerned, call your vet.

Answer (score 10):

While this answer isn't going to be comprehensive, I had heard of one danger from cats in Florida eating lizards (though this is not contained to Florida), and [this PetMD article](http://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/infectious-parasitic/c_ct_liver_fluke_infestation) confirmed it.  When a cat eats a lizard, you have to be careful of a **liver fluke infestation**, which can be acquired from eating lizards which have eaten liver fluke themselves.

According to the article, which you should read because it'll be more informative than this, many cats do not display symptoms, but symptomatic cats could display any number of gastrointestinal symptoms: from fever, vomiting and diarrhea, to anorexia, jaundice, weight loss, and/or stomach distention.  True diagnosis is only through microscopic observation of biopsied liver cells, or by identifying eggs in the cat's feces.  Treatment requires hospitalization.  **You can prevent an infestation by administering a periodic preventative medicine from your veterinarian;** this will probably not work on a cat that is already infected.

Check with your veterinarian; I am not a veterinarian.

Answer (score 1):

Before you panic too much, think about this: in the wild your cat would hunt down rats, birds and probably small lizards.

The real hazard are the bones of the lizard (if it had any) that could harm your furry friend. If you see him/her not eating or purring all the time (cats purr when they feel pain) then go to the vet.